# Sum of a measure column used in a further measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix, in which there is a measure that calculates month on month progress in a column called progress

This is the code for it:

```
Progress = 

VAR diff = 
CALCULATE(SUM('forecasting'[forecast]),PARALLELPERIOD('forecasting'[month],-1,MONTH))

RETURN SUM('forecasting'[forecast]) - diff
```

I need to calculate where the monthly change has been allocated across items as a percentage with the following formula:

```
(individual forecast value / sum of calculated progress measure for whole month) * 100
```

How can I use the total progress measure across the whole month? I've tried using a SUMX(), as seen below, but this didn't work and many values came to 100. Is is even possible to do this?

```
Change = 
VAR Total = 
SUMX('forecasting', 'forecasting'[Progress])

RETURN ((forecasting[Progress] / Total) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Change = 
VAR Total = 
CALCULATE(forecasting[Progress],FILTER(ALLSELECTED(forecasting),'forecasting'[month] = SELECTEDVALUE('forecasting'[month])))

RETURN ((forecasting[Progress] / Total) * 100)
```